# Ldap search filter multiple groups - squid

Tags: search, filter, ldap, squid

I am testing suid + AD using windows server 2008. I have the following simple structure for now:

```
+ Test_Users
-----internet_group
--------Matthew Vassallo (user)
-----normal_group
--------Kenneth Grech (user)
```

I would like to make an ldap query that contains a single common OU but with different groups. The following query worked out well for only one group and one OU:

```
(&(memberOf=OU=Test_Users,CN=internet_group,DC=matthew,DC=com)(sAMAccountName=%s))
```

How can I extend that please for more different groups? Thanks

Comment: You should fix the query, CN=... should be in the left side.

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
(&(memberOf=CN=%s,OU=Test_Users,DC=matthew,DC=com)(sAMAccountName=%s))
```

Then:

```
external_acl_type ldap_group %LOGIN /path/to/squid_ldap_group ...
acl group1 external ldap_group internet_group
acl group2 external ldap_group normal_group
http_access allow internet_group
http_access allow normal_group
```

Another option is to build a complex filter:

```
(&(|(memberOf=CN=normal_group,OU=Test_Users,DC=matthew,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=internet_group,OU=Test_Users,DC=matthew,DC=com))(sAMAccountName=%s))
```

Choose the best option for you :)

Comment: the 2nd string is such a life-saver, Kudos!

Comment: Ditto Life saver for me too

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me **(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(|(ou:dn:=Users1)(ou:dn:=Users2)))**

You need to be sure of the unique user uids!

```
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost/dc=ldapserver?uid?sub?(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(|(ou:dn:=Users1)(ou:dn:=Users2))) NONE
    Require ldap-group cn=wsgihg,ou=WebAuth,dc=ldapserver
```